# Getting a Public Feed from a facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, web, feed, public

Im looking for a tutorial or a script to get a public feed from my companies facebook page and displaying it on our website.

I haven't done too much research into the Facebook SDK and was wondering if there was a tutorial or something to help me accomplish this.

Comment: Something like this would work for you (the demo is for profiles but it works with pages, too) http://retrogram.eu/demos/adamsposts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
GET /{page_id}/feed
```

endpoint to retrieve the publically available feed contents. For example, /40796308305/feed will give you the feed of the CocaCola page.